# specified cast in not valid when getting "numeric" datatype from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

what is wrong with my code? i am reading the Quantity depending on the Model per Row from my gridview, the system reads the Model but when reader loop comes in, the error "Specified Cast is not Valid" occurs.

the Quantity datatype in the DB is numeric;
here is my code

```
for(int y = 0; y < dt.Rows.Count;y++)
        {
            model = dt.Rows[y]["ItemModel"].ToString();

            Utility a = new Utility();
            string com = a.connectPO();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(com);
            SqlCommand read = con.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader = null;

            string mod = "SELECT Quantity from vConsumables_Balance where Model ='" + model + "' AND Company = 'YLPI'";

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                read.CommandText = mod;
                reader = read.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch(System.Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                quan = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
            }

            dt.Rows[y]["lblAMS"] = quan;

        }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: why the `while` is out side the `try`?

Comment: what is the actual data type of the column any scale ? perhaps you should use `GetDecimal`

Comment: Squirrel, yup the GetDecimal worked! thanks!